# How to make different style in same text widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

How to apply different styles for different part of displayed text. How to do this in flutter?

Example:

> Hello ***World***

Answer (score 12):

This can be achieved using `RichText`

```
RichText(
     text: TextSpan(
          text: 'Hello',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.black),
          children: <TextSpan>[
             TextSpan(
               text: 'World',
               style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
               ),
             ),
          ]
     ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  return RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Can you ',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(
        text: 'find the',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.green,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
          decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.wavy,
        ),
        recognizer: _longPressRecognizer,
      ),
      TextSpan(text: 'secret?'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `RichText` will ignore OS font scale settings (accessibility) or global config TextScaler.

Use `Text.rich` as an alternative.

```
const Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: "Hello", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
      TextSpan(text: "World", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
    ],
  ),
),
```